# react-native with redux error

Tags: react-native, redux

I follow the demo to create a project. I used react-native with redux, then I get this error *"undefined is not a function(evaluating '(0, _redux.createStore)(_todoListRedux.reducer)')`"*.

This is my code:

index.android.js

```
import {AppRegistry, View} from 'react-native'
import {createStore} from 'redux'
import {reducer} from './todoListRedux'

const store = createStore(reducer)
import App from './App'

const AppWithStore = () => <App store={store} />

AppRegistry.registerComponent('redux', () => AppWithStore)
```

todoListRedux.js

```
export const types = {
  ADD: 'ADD',
  REMOVE: 'REMOVE',
}
export const actionCreators = {
  add: (item) => {
    return {type: types.ADD, payload: item}
   },
  remove: (index) => {
    return {type: types.REMOVE, payload: index}
  }
}
const initialState = {
  todos: ['Click to remove', 'Learn React Native','Write Code','Ship App'],
}
export const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  const {todos} = state
  const {type, payload} = action
  switch(type) {
    case types.ADD: {
     return {
        ...state,
        todos: [payload, ...todos],
      }
    }
    case types.REMOVE: {
      return {
        ...state,
        todos: todos.filter((todo,i) => i !== payload),
      }
    }
  }
  return state
}
```

any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Do you really inject store to react context in App? Something like <Provider store={store}> from react-redux package?

Answer (score 0):

The store added in `createStore`. Should be a store with `combineReducers`.

And as far as I know, the `middleware` should be passed as second parameter in the `createStore`.

Something like.

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
import rootReducer from '../store';

const middleware = applyMiddleware({you can pass here (logger or thunk, or the available options)});

//example
const middleware = applyMiddleware(thunk);

const store = createStore(rootReducer, middleware);
```

Comment: According to docs & sources, createStore(reducer) should be enough, other arguments optional.